# Unable to merge dex -Android 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-multidex

I have Android Studio 3.0.1. After added new library, when I tried launching the app it did not launch with the message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

But I don't know how to solve this error. I googled this but with no success.

My app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxxxx.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0.1"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/KGJsonConverter.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile 'com.github.amigold.fundapter:library:1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
compile files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.3.0'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0'}
```

my project gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'}}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google() maven{ url 'https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/'}}}task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dependencies below.

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.3.3@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.3@aar'
compile('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```